# Update panel and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a paged data-source in an update panel. I have it set up that when i click a next button the next page is returned via a partial post-back. The problem is that i am using the dreaded moo-tools lightface's / update-panel combo. Using this, the update panel and moo-tools wont work.

Is there some way around using the update panel, like some sort of jQuery Ajax paged data source?

I hope i have been clear and someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me your code here?

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageLoad() {
   /// Javascript Code Here for above mentioned Jquery by you.....
}
```

more you get from this post : http://forums.asp.net/t/1189519.aspx/1

Comment: Hii Wesley Skeen, If you find this question helps you.. please, select it as answer...or give me comment on this...